# Custom textbox in wordpress woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to get a normal text instead to use a slug? I need to use this custom code for Wordpress WooCommerce product page. The small problem the output get small letters and line "-" between words.

```
<?php /*CUSTOM MID*/ else: ?>


                <td class="value">
                    <select id="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title($name) ); ?>" 
                            name="attribute_<?php echo sanitize_title($name); ?>">
                    <option value="">
                        <?php echo __('Choose an option', 'woocommerce') ?>&hellip;
                    </option>

                    <?php
                        if ( is_array( $options ) ) {

                            if ( empty( $_POST ) )
                                $selected_value = ( isset( $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) ? $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ] : '';
                            else
                                $selected_value = isset( $_POST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ? $_POST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ] : '';

                            // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered
                            if ( taxonomy_exists( sanitize_title( $name ) ) ) {

                                $terms = get_terms( sanitize_title($name), array('menu_order' => 'ASC') );

                                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                    if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) ) continue;
                                    echo '<option value="' . $term->slug . '" ' . selected( $selected_value, $term->slug, false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>';
                                }
                            } else {
                                foreach ( $options as $option )
                                    echo '<option value="' . $option . '" ' . selected( $selected_value, $option, false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    </select> <?php
                    if ( sizeof($attributes) == $loop )
                        echo '<a class="reset_variations" href="#reset">'.__('Clear selection', 'woocommerce').'</a>';
                ?></td>
```

Comment: You should try with this website : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: _“can somebody explain this code for me”_ – the whole of it? No. If you lack the knowledge to understand the code in general, then please work through some PHP beginner tutorials. If you have _specific_ questions about certain parts of it, then please ask _specific_ questions as well.

Answer (score 0):

remove `-` you can do it by pure php using `str_replace`

You have to give us more of your code to understand it.